# Summation equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Recently encountered the following problem:

$$x_n = x_1 - 2 a \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{a}{x_i} \right)$$,

where $n>1$, and $x_1$ is known. The task is to find $x_n$ for arbitrary n. It resembles an integral equation, but in a discrete form. What are the possible tricks to solve for that?

P.S.: Of course, one can try to solve it iteratively, but then the answer becomes cumbersome quickly. Although no one promised me that this particular problem has a nice and compact answer at all.

Comment: I would start by evaluating $x_n-x_{n-1}$, it would give the nice recursive $x_n=x_{n-1}-2a-\frac{2a^2}{x_{n-1}}$.

Comment: Also the transformation $y_n = x_n/a-1$ will reduce it to $y_n = y_{n-1}(y_{n-1}-1)/(y_{n-1}+1)$.  Doubt that has an exact solution, but could do some interesting asymptotics (i.e. seems like generically $y_n \to 0$ but subgeometrically).

Comment: Hi, @UdiFogiel I did that! And tried to look at that as a diff. equation, and it seems that it behaves somehow close to Lambert function, but need to have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, most likely its impossible to solve it analytically in a discrete form, but in a continuous form - yes, you can make a good estimation.

First of all by considering $y_{n+1}-y_{n}$ we can get the following differential equation:
$$ y'(x)=-2a+\frac{2a^2}{y(x)}, \quad y(x=1)=x_1,$$
the solution of which is given by:

$$ y(x) = a \left( W\left(\exp \left( -2 x + \frac{c_1}{a} -1 - \ln(a) \right) \right) - 1 \right), $$
where $W(x)$ is the Lambert W function, and the constant $с_1$ is found from the initial condition $y(x=1)=x_1$ (If anyone knows how to write it analytically -  I would be grateful).

I compared a continuous solution with a discrete one, and in the limit I am interested in $x_1 \gg a$ it works for small $n$.

[image: Results]

It is not that precise when $x_1 \sim a$, but very good at $x_1 \gg a$. Moreover, it seems that after that linearly decaying part, the continuous solution shows the average between $x_n$ for even $n$, and odd $n$. The only thing left is to estimate $n$ at which the linear decay stops.

Comment: If I am not mistaken $$y(x)=a \Bigg[1+W\left(\frac{x_1-a }{a}\,\,e^{-2x+\left(\frac{x_1+a}{a}\right)}\right)\Bigg]$$ Nice problem and (+1).

Comment: Long time no see :). Yet another problem from me with Lambert function. It comes from some quantum mechanical problem, and the fact that $x_n$ linearly decays with $n$ actually means that the model is bullshit, hehe. But we are working on modifying such that it works at least in some range of parameters.

Comment: When I saw the problem, I thought that it could be related to QM. I am myself a quantum mechanicist (working more precisely with wave mechanics). For a year and half (long time ago) I have been LdB last student). I hope you see who he is (for me, my guru is still alive). Cheers :-)